# Parallelization/Cluster Options For Code Execution

Tags: scala, jakarta-ee, architecture, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I'm coming from a java background and have a CPU bound problem that I'm trying to parallelize to improve performance. I have broken up my code to perform in a modular way so that it can be distributed and run in a parallel way (hopefully).

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void runMyJob(List<String> some params){
  doComplexEnoughStuffAndWriteToMysqlDB();
}
```

Now, I have been thinking of the following options for parallelizing this problem and I'd like people's thoughts/experience in this area.

Options I am currently thinking of:

1) Use Java EE (eg JBoss) clustering and MessageDrivenBeans. The MDBs are on the slave nodes in the cluster. Each MDB can pick up an event which kicks off a job as above. AFAIK Java EE MDBs are multithreaded by the app server so this should hopefully also be able to take advantage of multicores. Thus it should be vertically and horizontally scalable.

2) I could look at using something like Hadoop and Map Reduce. Concerns I would have here is that my job processing logic is actually quite high level so I'm not sure how translatable that is to Map Reduce. Also, I'm a total newbie to MR.

3) I could look at something like Scala which I believe makes concurrency programming much simpler. However, while this is vertically scalable, it's not a cluster/horizontally scalable solution.

Anyway, hope all that makes sense and thank you very much for any help provided.

Comment: Akka provides robust remote actor capability for Scala, so I'm not sure that it is fair to say that Scala isn't horizontally scalable.  (In fact, even the core Scala library provides some support for remote actors.)

Comment: Hi Rex, thanks, that's exactly the type of thing I suppose that I don't know much about. So, is it easy to distribute jobs across nodes with scala and Akka ? Would you recommend it over say using a JBoss cluster?

Comment: I'm afraid don't know enough to recommend either; I just know that it's a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [spark](http://spark-project.org).
It is a cluster computing framework written in Scala aiming at being a viable alternative to Hadoop.
It has a number of nice feats:

- In-Memory Computations: You can control the degree of caching
- Hadoop Input/Output interoperability: Spark can read/write data from all the Hadoop input sources such as HDFS, EC2, etc.
- The concept of "Resilient Distributed Datasets" (RDD) which allows you to directly execute most of MR style workloads in parallel on a cluster as you would do locally
- Primary API = Scala, optional python and Java APIs
- It makes use of Akka :)

If I understand your question correctly, Spark would combine your options 2) and 3).

Answer (score 0):

the solution you are looking for is Akka. Clustering is a feature under development, and will normally be included in Akka 2.1

- Excellent Scala and Java Api, extremely complete
- Purely message-oriented pattern, with no shared state
- Fault resistant and scalable
- Extremely easy to distribute jobs

Please get rid of J2EE if you are still on time. You are very welcome to join the Akka mailing list to ask your questions.